# How to resolve conflict with merging with Github API

Tags: git, github, merge, github-api

I'm using the Github's **web API** to control my own fork and an upstream. The task is to pull from the upstream repo and merge into my fork. When there's a conflict, I want the API to force-merge the files, and display conflict in the file like this:

```
>>>>>>
This line is from my fork
======
This line is from upstream
<<<<<<
```

This can be automatically done with the git client when running **git pull** or **git merge**, but the Github API (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/merging/) will only fail if there's a conflict, and not try to make the conflict look like above. Is there any way to achieve the above with Github API? Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that GitHub will only approve a pull request (merge) if there are no conflicts.  Why would you want GitHub to leave a remote branch in a partially merged state?

Comment: The reason is after the "partial merging" there will be a web page that displays the partially merged file, and the user can manually edit it and resolve conflict, just like how it's done with git client.

Comment: Supporting this feature would mean that a remote branch on the repository could be in a transient state.  How would you deal with the problem of a colleague trying to pull or push to a branch that were in merge conflict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not possible currently with the GitHub API (nor via the GitHub UI). That's a neat idea, though -- I'll mention it to the team to consider, and if you'd like to share more details about what you're building, please reach out via support@github.com.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Ivan! I'll send an Email to support@github.com and explain in details.

Comment: @menphix - I'm in the same boat. Any fix from GitHub API on this or any advise?

Comment: Samsies.  Seems like there wont be a `force` flag coming

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close to re-creating this behavior by using a combination of the GitHub [Commits API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits) and 2 command line programs: [merge](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/merge.htm) and [diff](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm).

I would guess that in your design the conflicted files are saved locally to disk or presented in the web browser. If you are trying to do this in a web browser, you may need to put the approach described below behind your own API.

With the Commits API, [compare 2 commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits). Do it in the direction that you want to merge. The 'files' key in the response from the API call will give you all of the conflicted, added, and deleted (I think) files.

The base_commit key, found in the response json, is the commit into which you are merging your branch. The merge_base_commit key is the common ancestor of your commit/branch and the target(i.e. base_commit) commit/branch. Both of these are at the top level.

For each file in the files key you need to figure out if there is a merge_base_commit version of the file. If so then you will do a 3 way merge, just like git using merge: merge -p file(commits[last]) file(merge_base_commit) file(base_commit) which will give you the conflict tagged file that you seek.

If there isn't a merge_base_commit version of the file, you would use: diff -DCONFLICT file(commits[last]) file(base_commit). The -D parameter will give you a marked up file, very similar to what you want. A simple regex to replace the merge tags will make it look like the git conflict tags.

To get the 3 versions of your file, start with the 'contents_url' key out of each file key. The contents_url as-is will get you your version of the file. Replace the ref query string parameter with the sha from both your base_commit and merge_base_commit: results['merge_base_commit']['sha'] and results['base_commit']['sha'].

Once you have all 3 files you can do your three-way merge using the merge program. If you get a 404 on the merge_base_commit get, this means you need to do a two-way merge. If you get a 404 on the base_commit get, this mean that your file doesn't exist on the target branch, so there isn't anything to do from the perspective of adding conflict tags.

Comment: Thank you webfanatic! I'll have to try this out to see if it'll work for me, but looks promising! One thing is I can't run any linux command/program in my environment, so I'll have to figure out something with pure python. Your suggestion is definitely a good starting point.